# Generic tail in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, tail

`tail` for array:

```
private extension Array {
    var tail: Array { get { return Array(dropFirst(self)) } }
}
```

And here is generic version for `Sliceable`:

```
public func tail<S: Sliceable>(sequence: S, initializer: ((S.SubSlice) -> S)) -> S {
    return initializer(dropFirst(sequence))
}
let s = tail("12", {String($0)})
```

Is it possible to rewrite generic `tail` without `initializer` arg?
I.e. call `initializer` via sequence type (`S()` or something)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a sliceable type `T`, `T.SubSlice` can be different from `T`.
For example `String.SubSlice == String`, but `Array.SubSlice == ArraySlice<T>`.

You can define a *protocol* which describes all types which can be
created from their own subslices:

```
public protocol CreatableFromSubslice : Sliceable {
    init(_ subslice : Self.SubSlice)
}
```

Even if most (all?) built-in sliceable types can be created from their own
subslice, you still have to tell that the compiler with empty
extensions:

```
extension String : CreatableFromSubslice { }
extension Array : CreatableFromSubslice { }
// ...
```

Then `tail()` can be defined as

```
public func tail<S: CreatableFromSubslice>(slice: S) -> S {
    return S(dropFirst(slice))
}
```

Example:

```
let s = tail("12")
println(s) // "2"

let a = tail([1, 2, 3])
println(a) // [2, 3]
```

---

For types which are *equal* to their subslice type you could define

```
public func tail<S: Sliceable where S.SubSlice == S >(slice: S) -> S {
    return dropFirst(slice)
}
```

This can be applied to `String`, but not to `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply, it seems specialised tail is more practical ATM :|